# Copy data's from one workbook to another workbook through Command Line

Tags: excel, command, prompt, xlsm

I would like to copy data from Excel(xlsx) to macro enabled file(xlsm) through command prompt. I have used the following syntax

```
copy sourcefile destinationfile
```

Above command works fine for two xlsx or two xlsm files. If I try to copy from xlsx to xlsm , while opening, macro enabled file is corrupted.

Does anyone have idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This might be better asked at [SuperUser](http://www.superuser.com), as it's more related to the OS than Excel.

Comment: does it have to be command prompt?  http://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/8269/Convert-between-Excel-file-formats-XLS-XLSX-XLSM-with-without-macro-option.html